# Algorithmic noun plural

Tags: languages, grammar

I'm looking for an (implementation of) a command (here `\plural`) that computes the  plural of a noun.

The algorithm should work as follows:

- for most cases, simply add `s` at the end (example: `bag` -> `bags`).
- If the word ends with `ss`, `es` must be added (example: `class` -> `classes`).
- If the word ends with `y` and the one but last letter is not a vowal, `y` is replaced by `ies` (example `story` -> `stories`)
- ...

Is there a package for this, if not, how does one implement this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any package that does this. Unfortunately English is such a hotchpotch of different languages that any algorithm will have to cope with all the exceptions such as child/children, sheep/sheep, goose/geese, mouse/mice, die/dice (small cube with spots) or die/dies (metal moulds), potato/potatoes, bravo/bravoes (hired thug) or bravo/bravos (applause).

Comment: True, but in such case, one could enter the plural him/herself. Having a command however that succeeds calculating most of the plural nouns, could ease some tasks...

Comment: You might be able to use `l3regex`.

Comment: To see some sense of the problem and an actual algorithm: http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/papers/HTML/Plurals.html